# Why is this saying the list isn't populated?

Tags: python

```
s = raw_input("Give me some numbers: ")
numbers = map(int, s.split())
i = int(raw_input("how many iterations?"))
print numbers
while i > 0:
    first_num = numbers.pop(0)
    second_num = numbers.pop(0)
    largest = 0
    if first_num > largest and second_num < first_num:
        largest = first_num
    elif second_num > largest and second_num > first_num:
        largest = second_num
    else:
        largest = largest
    i -= 1

 print largest
```

So this is just a simple while loop in Python meant to take a set of numbers, two at a time, compare them and then set the variable `largest` to the largest of the two. I keep getting the error `IndexError: pop from empty list` even though the list is quite obviously populated (a print statement on line 4 proved that). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Put the `print` statement inside the loop. Currently, it only proves that the list was *initially* populated.

Comment: If it says `IndexError: pop from empty list` that means list is definitely empty. We have to find out...  why ?

Comment: First of all... you are removing one element from list on each `numbers.pop()`.

Comment: oh wow! thanks! strangely enough, it seems that my iterations should for some reason be divided by two because it's taking two items from the list each time it loops?

Comment: Also... In each iteration you are trying to remove two numbers from list. what if your iterations are `100` and number in list are only `50` or `150`. Also... what if the number of elements is odd ? Make sure double of iteration is not more than number of elements.

Comment: You can always check the number of iterations entered and make sure it's less than `len(numbers)/2` and that should handle the case of trying to pop too many numbers from your `numbers` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get some numbers, let's say you have 9 Numbers.

Then, you ask for the number of iterations. Let's say i put 7 here.

The loop will run 7 times, taking 2 Numbers each. So eventually, you run out of numbers.

Comment: I guess... I will upvote this for now... but please do not create answers with so less content. read [answer]

Comment: @ben Please make sure to accept this answer as appreciation of the effort put by Sebastian.

Comment: @Kevin It completely and nicely answers  the OP's question. But I just wanted to mention that if he was creating an answer... he should  have added few more details. But still considering that he is new here... he will improve in his future answers.

Comment: sorry for going meta, but: how does my answer not fulfill the criteria? The question was about running out of numbers. Without any example input/output, I was making up some data to demonstrate how you could run out of numbers. I still don't know what the purpose of this piece of code actually is.

Comment: Well... There is no rule which says that your answer is a bad answer. But nothing says that it is a good answer too. Because good answers need to have something good about them. "Just" a right answer is not a good answer. And please believe me my friend when I say that this is not a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would rewrite this:

```
s           = raw_input("Give me some numbers: ")
numbers     = [int(i) for i in s.split()]

max_pairs   = int(raw_input("How many iterations? "))
max_len     = max_pairs * 2

first_nums  = numbers[0:max_len:2]
second_nums = numbers[1:max_len:2]

for fn,sn in zip(first_nums, second_nums):
    largest = max(fn, sn, 0)
    print(largest)
```